# C# Socket: What if BeginSend is called before BeginReceive?

Tags: c#, sockets

I got a TCP ping/pong working, but after trying to add a second data type, I run into a situation where the receiving program never fires the `BeginReceive` callback.

The code is identical, except that with the second (problematic) data type, serialization is done ahead of time. This leads me to believe that the problem may lie in that `BeginSend` is called sooner with the second data type, perhaps before `BeginReceive` is called in the other program.

Alternatively, I wonder if the difference in data size.

So my question for SO is: Is it possible that send before receive is the problem? If so, how does one handle that? If not, what else could be going wrong?

## Common

```cs
enum DataType : byte { A, B }
```

## Data Receiver

```cs
TcpListener _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 2323);
DataType _expectedDataType;

Constructor() { _listener.Start(); }

Connect() { _listener.BeginAcceptSocket(OnConnect, null); }

OnConnect(IAsyncResult result)
{
    _socket = _listener.EndAcceptSocket(result);
    _socket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
    _socket.SendTimeout = 1000;
    _expectedDataType = DataType.A;
    if (_socket.Connected)
        ReceiveData();
    else
        Connect();
}

ReceiveData()
{
    Debug.Log("Receiving " + _expectedDataType + " Data");
    // EDIT: The problem lied in the fact that the length parameter is sometimes longer than the first length parameter that was ever used
    _socket.BeginReceive(_dataBuffer[(int)_expectedDataType], 0, _dataBuffer[_expectedDataType].Length, SocketFlags.None, OnReceiveData, null);
    // buffer array is 119 for A, 133 for B
}

OnReceiveData(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var bytes = _socket.EndReceive(result);
    Debug.Log("Received " + bytes + "bytes of " + _expectedDataType + " Data");

    // ... Deserialize several variables from the buffer based on data type ...

    if (_needToUpdateBData)
        _expectedDataType = DataType.B;
    else
        _expectedDataType = DataType.A

    _socket.BeginSend(new[]{(byte)_expectedDataType}, 0, 1, SocketFlags.None, OnSendRequest, null);
}

OnSendRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var bytes = _socket.EndSend(result);
    Debug.Log("Sent " + _expectedDataType + " Request " + bytes + "bytes");
    ReceiveData();
}
```

## Data Sender

```cs
TcpClient _client = new TcpClient();
DataType _expectedDataType;

OnEnterIpAddress(string ipAddress) { _client.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), 2323, OnClientConnect, null); }

OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult result)
{
    _client.EndConnect(result);
    _stream = _client.GetStream();
    _expectedDataType = DataType.A;
    SendData();
}

SendData()
{
    // ... Serialize into buffer based on expectedDataType
    // This is where A takes a long time, and B is nearly instant ...
    var bytes = _buffer[(int)_expectedDataType].Length;
    Debug.Log("Sending " + _expectedDataType + " data with length of " + bytes + "bytes");
    _stream.BeginWrite(_buffer[(int)_expectedDataType], 0, bytes, OnWrite, null);
}

OnWrite(IAsyncCallback)
{
    _stream.EndWrite(result);
    Debug.Log("Sent " + _expectedDataType + " data, awaiting response");
    _stream.BeginRead(_response, 0, 1, OnRead, null);
}

OnRead(IAsyncCallback)
{
    var bytes = _stream.EndRead(result);
    Debug.Log("Received " + bytes + "bytes of " + _expectedDataType + " data");
    _expectedDataType = (DataType)_response[0];
    SendData();
}
```

If I disable `_needToUpdateBData`, so that only `A` Data is ever sent, the two parts go back and forth swimmingly. If `_needToUpdateBData` is set to true, the sender will get stuck on "Sent B data, awaiting response", and the receiver will get stuck on "Receiving B Data", meaning the `OnReciveData` callback is never fired.

Even after setting Socket.ReceiveTimeout to 1000ms, its left hanging on "Receiving B Data" indefinitely.

Note that try/catches are missing because I intended to get this back and forth working before complicating things with reconnection logic (actually, several have been removed to make this post more concise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that send before receive is the problem?

No, one side of a TCP connection can never know for sure that the other one has a pending read. Even if the remote side wants to issue a read its threads might be descheduled for a long time. TCP must be able to work without this guarantee. This cannot possibly be a concern.

```
var bytes = _socket.EndReceive(result);
Debug.Log("Received " + bytes + "bytes of " + _expectedDataType + " Data");

// ... Deserialize several variables from the buffer based on data type ...
```

This looks like the classic bug where you assume that a single read call will return all the data you want to have. Instead, it can return a partial result. You cannot possibly deserialize with a single read call so I assume this is a case of this classic bug.

The timeouts do not work for async IO (I don't know why, it's terrible). Probably, you should not be using async IO anyway. I can tell because you are accepting sockets asynchronously with is a pure waste of dev time. That makes me think that you have not consciously made the decision between sync and async IO.

```
if (_socket.Connected)
```

How could this be false right after connecting? Makes no sense. Do not copy code from other source without understanding what it does. This is a common anti-pattern.

Sockets are really hard to get right. The best choice usually is to use something ready-made such as WCF, HTTP, websockets etc.

Comment: "This looks like the classic bug where you assume that a single read call will return all the data you want to have..." I came across that in other SO answers. I can cofirm that all 133 bytes are being received every time in the single Read. Regardless, the proposed solution is to do a second Read and expect a result of 0, but the callback on my next BeginRead is never called, so I would never be able to get 0 from EndRead anyways. Or is this "bug" triggered by doing a send in-between reads?

Comment: The `if (_socket.Connected)` was intended to handle failed connections based on an early misunderstanding of how the callbacks worked. Not copypasted.

Good to know about the timeout bug, thanks.

This is asynchronous to prevent locking the GUI, and WCF/HTTP are avoided because performance is vital (ideally packets will be sent back and forth 90 times per second. Any less than 60 is unacceptable, but accuracy is even more important thus TCP over UDP).

Comment: Read only returns zero when the stream ends. When there is no data left and the connection is still open it just blocks forever. Regarding the "classic bug", you have that bug but it looks like it is not coming into play. You need to fix that, though... Can you post the code that you left out. As far as I can mentally verify the code should work (besides the spurious failure induced by the missing read loop).

Comment: `Not copypasted` OK, fair enough. It just looked like it based on my Stack Overflow experience. Sorry about that.

Comment: I recommend that you use synchronous code on a background thread (e.g. `Task.Run`). Or, use await together with `NetworkStream`. There also are TAP extension methods for socket. The APM pattern explodes code complexity.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into how to do that.

Comment: For the record, it looks like having an expected stream length of longer than the A data-type's length is causing the hang. Perhaps a bug in Socket where it expects subsequent Reads to be of smaller or same size as the first?

Anyways, you answered the main question, which was whether or not order of send/receive matters and pointed out bugs in Thread's async methods. Checking answer.

Comment: `Perhaps a bug in Socket` No, the bug is with you. I guarantee you that :) `expected stream length of longer than the A data-type's length` sounds like your deserialization code cannot deal with the fact that a read might read multiple app-level messages in one go

Comment: It doesn't even reach the deserialization code when it hangs. I've confirmed that the hang happens even after data was sent. Changing the size parameter to a smaller number prevented the hang.

This is using Mono, an open source implementation of .Net 2.0, so I wouldn't be surprised if it's a bug.

Switching to the synchronous methods with my own asynchronous implementation as suggested above fixed the problem.

Comment: OK, with Mono it could be a bug. But almost always when you change some buffer size constant or reading pattern and it starts to work your code has some invalid dependency on the specific read sizes.